# return value from devtools.inspectedwindow.eval

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to return the value of an eval to my function and I have not been able to get it working. I have tried a few things all which have been giving me null or undefined. Here is my code

```
    this.isLoggedIn = function()
{
    var q = 'document.getElementById("game").contentWindow["' + windowMembers[gints] + '"]["' + gamevars[lints] + '"]["' + loginvars[l2ints] + '"]()["' + loginvars2[flogin] + '"]()';
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(q, function(s,e){console.log(s); s});

};
```

The console.log shows the correct value is being received in the callback function

I have also tried

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(q, function(s,e){console.log(s); return s});

return chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(q, function(s,e){console.log(s); s});

return chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(q, function(s,e){console.log(s); return s});
```

none of these have worked for me and I believe it has something to do with the fact that.

A: chrome.devtools.inspectedWidow.eval does NOT return a value

B: when returning a value from the callback function it is just ending said callback function

so I was hoping some one here could help me achieve the following

run the function isLoggedIn()

have the eval run on the query

obtain the value of the query (in this case true\false)

have the isLoggedIn function return the eval data

I am writing this for a devtools extensions for debugging certain html5\js games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are confused with the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. If you call `isLoggedIn` it returns before `function(s,e){console.log(s); s}` is executed.

Add a `console.log('test')` at the very end of `isLoggedIn` and observe order in which messages are displayed on the console.

Your issue has nothing to do with chrome or chrome-extensions, what you need to read about is handling asynchronous functions in JavaScript. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/14220323) for a good explanation and ways to solve it (said question is about AJAX, but that's just a detail).